# Google Analytics 4 SSIS Integration using Kingswaysoft - Metrics & Dimensions not getting listed wit Google Analytics Data API

Tags: google-analytics, ssis, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, kingswaysoft

[image][image]

Hello,

Looking for some guidance/help. I'm trying to integrate GA4 with SSIS using Kingswaysoft. When I use 'Google Analytics Data API' Metrics & Dimensions do not appear in the dropdown list (as seen in the attached images). I'm using visual studio 2019.

Here is the link to Metrics and Dimensions that should be available under 'Google Analytics Data API' & 'Google Analytics Real-time Data API': https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

Please advice what might be possible issue here that I'm not able to notice to get the correct drop down dimensions and metrics list for 'Google Analytics Data API'

Thank you!

Was expecting to see all the metrics and dimensions list as described in GA4. Tested connection Manager which works fine.
I have entered Property ID that is necessary for Data API.

Tried Google Analytics Real-Time Data API which works fine. But when I try with Google Analytics Data API I encounter the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question. Do you see an error message in SSIS?

You may not be seeing all the dimensions and metrics because the token does not have the permissions required to access them and is only displaying the ones you do have access to. To resolve this issue, try giving the account authorizing the token the appropriate permissions. After this, you will need to generate a new token and see if the dimensions you are looking for are populated in the component.

Please upgrade to our latest official version if you have a previous version of the Productivity Pack installed. We have made some enhancements in our most recent version. When upgrading, make a backup of your Visual Studio Integration Service Project before opening it using our latest build, since all components will be automatically upgraded to the newest version. Backups allow you to revert to previous versions. Download link: kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/download Please give this a try and let us know if you have any questions

Comment: Hello @kingswaysoft I get "Error 400: Invalid_Request" on Google Chrome (windows server 2019 operating system). Seems like a developer issue.

Comment: Hello @kingswaysoft, Please see complete error message in detail.                            
Error 400: invalid_request
The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure. Follow the Out-of-Band (OOB) flow migration guide linked in the developer docs below to migrate your app to an alternative method.
Request details: redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
Related developer documentation

Comment: Hi @Uranium1989, Please upgrade to our latest official version if you have a previous version of the Productivity Pack installed. We have made some enhancements in our most recent version. When upgrading, make a backup of your Visual Studio Integration Service Project before opening it using our latest build, since all components will be automatically upgraded to the newest version. Backups allow you to revert to previous versions.

Download link: https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/download

Please give this a try and let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hello @kingswaysoft, Thank you, that seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no knowledge of [kingswaysoft's GA4 component](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/help-manual/google-services/google-analytics-source), but I did just wrap up a UA to GA4 reporting project.

- A metric is a countable thing, like number of cows. "I have 10 cows"
- A dimension describes the metric. "I have 6 black cows and 4 white ones"

I would guess that the metric you're selecting or perhaps the dimension results in Kingswaysoft filtering out the incompatible dimensions. For example, it seemed that any time I attempted to add the dimension `pagePathPlusQueryString` to my queries, it'd error out with

> Please remove pagePathPlusQueryString to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible.

As you paid for the product, it might not hurt to reach out to them regarding the challenges you're having.